# Printing full date in bibliography (BibLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex, datetime

How can I get biblatex to print the full date in the references?  I could have sworn it used to do this all by itself and I've got some old files where I've managed this, but I can't see anything in the .tex file or in the biblatex manual that says how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @article{Article,
  title = {This is a Title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  journal = {Journal},
  location = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2014-04-23}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}
Citing \cite{Article}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lack of full date in bibliography]

Comment: Does `mergedate=false`, `mergedate=compact` or `mergedate=minimum` help? Please see [*The `mergedate` option* in the quide to *The `authoryear-icomp` style*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/53-style-authoryear-icomp.pdf). You probably want `mergedate=basic`.

Comment: `mergedate=basic`, `mergedate=false`, and `mergedate=minimum` all seem to have more or less the same effect and put the date just after the title or the journal title, which I'm quite happy with, although I do remember that it did used to appear after the author.  Thanks very much!

Comment: There are minute differences between the three as explained in the document above, you might not notice them in your document though. If you prefer to get the full date in the parentheses after the author that could probably be arranged as well. Have a look at the `datelabel` option (p. 51 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)), you could give `datelabel=comp` a try.

Answer (score 7):

The `mergedate` option is what you are looking for. See [The `authoryear-icomp` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/53-style-authoryear-icomp.pdf).

---

You might like `mergedate=false`.

> `mergedate=false` strictly separates the date specification from the
>   date label. The year will always be printed twice.

[image]

All dates are printed twice.

---

Or `mergedate=minimum`

> `mergedate=minimum` merges the dates whenever the full date and the
>   date label are exactly the same string. If the date is a bare year
>   number and there is no `extrayear` field, the date specification will
>   be omitted.

[image]

Knuth 1948's date is not printed twice here.

---

Or `mergedate=basic`

> `mergedate=basic` [...] will always omit the date specification if the date is a bare year number.

[image]

Knuth 1986a and Knuth 1986b's date are not printed twice either.

---

If you prefer the date to go into the parentheses at the front, you can use the `datelabel` option. The default value is `year`, so you only get to see the year. You can choose between `year`, `short`, `long`, `terse`, `comp` and `iso8601` (see pp. 50-51 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).
The latter options print the full date.

This option is probably best used with the default `mergedate=compact` option.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,backend=biber,datelabel=comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{baez/online,shore,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]